# Error on Disable submit form button after submit on a JSP page

Tags: jsp

So I have a form and I would like to disable the submit 'button' on the form after the user has clicked on it once to prevent multiple submits, and I was wondering how I will be able to achieve this result. So the code goes something like this:

```
<form id = "id" name= "blah" method = "post" onsubmit="$('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');" ...>
items for the form goes here
<input title="Save" type="submit" value="Save" tabindex="20"/>
```

But I'm getting an error in the console:
"Error: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object"

Comment: This is jQuery code. Do you have a script block importing the jQuery library in your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following code

onsubmit="document.getElementById('submit').disabled = 1;"

let me know if it is not works.

Comment: I get error on the page, but I figured out what to do, call a function with what you have "document.getElementById('submitBtn').disabled = true" and it worked. Thank you